# C++ template differentiation between typedefs of the same type

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I am working on a small game, and it works on typedef'd ids. I made a static id manager class that looks like this:

```
class MetaIdManager{
  template<typename T> static T             _lastAssigned;
  template<typename T> static std::queue<T> _freeIds;
public:
  template<typename T> static void freeId(const T id){
    _freeids.push(id);
  }

  template<typename T> static T getNewId(){
    if(_freeIds<T>.empty()){
        return _lastAssigned<T>++;
    }
    else {
        T val = _freeIds<T>.front();
        _freeIds<T>.pop();
        return val;
    }
  }

  template<typename T> static void reset(){
    std::swap(_freeIds<T>, std::queue<T>());
    _lastAssignedId<T> = 0;
  }
};

template<typename T> T MetaIdManager::_lastAssigned = {};
template<typename T> std::queue<T> MetaIdManager::_freeIds = {};
```

When I have two typedefs: `typedef long E_ID` and `typedef long A_ID`, and I call `getNewId()` for both an `E_ID` and `A_ID` they both get their values for the same generated template methods and variables. So while both should be 0, one of them is 0 and the other is 1.

Is it possible to differentiate between the two user defined types?

Comment: `E_ID` and `A_ID` name the same type. You'd need to wrap the `long` in a struct, or use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` or something.

Comment: When i did a BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(long, E_ID) and tried to call the getNewId() function, it threw a conversion error between long and E_ID, but it worked with a static_cast<T>(...). Is that normal behaviour? (... also, how do i highlight code in the comment?)

Comment: Which line? You use backticks (`) to highlight code in comments.

Comment: `getNewId()`-s return statements for example:  `return _lastAssigned<T>++;` will throw a conversion error between `long` and `E_ID`. But `return static_cast<T>(_lastAssigned<T>++)` compiles and works.

Comment: @val yes, because the strong typedef-ed doesn't have `operator++(int)`, then it need to be converted to `long`, and the construction from `long` to typedef-ed type is explicit, then you need to call `static_cast` to call that constructor